# React Native - Reading ByteArray (raw bytes) directly from file

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, file-read, raw

I'm uploading media files (images, wav files) from my phone to AWS S3 bucket. To upload to S3, finally I'll need the Byte array.

I'm using react-native-fs package and reading in base64, and then decoding it back to byteArray and then finally uploading it AWS S3

Currently, I'm doing the following,

```
let base64Data = await RNFS.readFile(fPath, 'base64');
const arrayBuffer = AWS.util.base64.decode(base64Data)
```

I'm trying to find a way to avoid the base64.decode() operation.

The Documentation of RNFS.readFile() [here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) says,

```
encoding can be one of utf8 (default), ascii, base64. Use base64 for reading binary files.
```

I also explored [RNFetchBlob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#readfilepath-encodingpromise) package and it uses the same encoding as above and I couldn't find any support for reading raw bytes in RNFetchBlob as well.

**Question:** Is there a way to directly read raw bytes from the file using react-native-fs package or any other React Native package?

Thank you.